# Weird for line in C

Tags: c, for-loop, hash

I saw this line of code from the OpenSubtitles website.
It uses a simple (if we exclude this line) algorith to generate a hash value from a movie.

The line of code is this:

```
for(uint64_t tmp = 0, i = 0; i < 65536/sizeof(tmp) && fread((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, handle); hash += tmp, i++);
```

No idea... All the action happens inside the for, instead of the format i was familiar with all these years...

```
for (x=0; x<=5; x++)
{/*do something here*/}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: The `fread((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, handle);` part is better written as `fread(&tmp, sizeof tmp, 1, handle);` since `fread()` takes a `void *` and `sizeof` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to understand if you write it like this:

```
for(
    uint64_t tmp = 0, i = 0; 
    i < 65536/sizeof(tmp) && fread((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, handle); 
    hash += tmp, i++)
{
}
```

It declares two variables, modifies two variables at each iteration (though not the same two), and makes a function call in the continue condition.  It's a more concise way of expressing this:

```
uint64_t tmp = 0;
uint64_t i = 0;
size_t res;
while (1)
{
    if (i >= 65536/sizeof(tmp))
        break;
    res = fread((char*)&tmp, sizeof(tmp), 1, handle);
    if (!res)
        break;
    hash += tmp;
    ++i;
}
```